How can I define the agent location of GIS Map using Parameters Longitude and Latitude?
I have the following problem, I have a population of agents living in the main agent. Now, the agent has two parameters longitude and latitude. The values of longitude and latitude vary between 56.88, 56.99 and -5.688, -5.788.
The values are generated at the agent On Start up Code.
But I am failing to initialize the agents on the GIS Map using the parameters Latitude and Longitude. I have tried using setLatLong(Latitude, Longitude), but this is not working.
enter image description here
Can you help me on this?

This question is similar to: How can I define the GIS locations of agents in anylogic?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Could you please liaise with the other students who asked the same question already, and got an answer?
